# Using the mean stack, how do you send an image back to the server?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack, mean.io

I'm using mean.io, where I've create a new package similar to articles. In it I create an image (using canvas.toDataURL()) and would now like to send it back to the server, but having issues; can someone please advise?

More specifically, what I have done so far is as follow:

In newpackages/public/controllers/newpackages.js //after creating image, I pass it to a sendImgToServer() method

```
'use strict';

angular.module('mean.newpackages').controller('NewpackagesController', ['$scope','$http',...,
function($scope, $stateParams, $http, ... Newpackages){

...

$scope.sendImgToServer = function(image){
    console.log(image);  //data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAoAAAARwCAYAAAB…
    var postURL = '/newpackages/saveImg';
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("image", image);

    $http.post(postURL, fd,{
        headers:{'Content-Type':undefined},
        transformRequest:angular.identity
    })
    .success(function(){
    })
    .error(function(){
    });
};
```

In newpackages/public/routes/newpackages.js

```
...

$stateProvider
  ...
  .state('save newpackage image', {
    url:'/newpackages/saveImg',
    resolve:{
      loggedin:checkLoggedin
    }
  });
}
```

In newpackages/server/controllers/newpackages.js

```
...

exports.saveImg = function(req, res){
    console.log('save img');
};
```

Lastly, in newpackages/server/routes/newpackages.js

```
...

app.route('/newpackages/:fd')
    .post(newpackages.saveImage);

...
```

In console, the error message I'm receiving is:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
  at Scope.$scope.sendImgToServer
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error your getting is because you're setting your content-type header to undefined in method sendImgToServer.

```
headers:{'Content-Type':undefined}
```

Set the appropriate header, for instance:

```
headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, iH8. I tried to change the headers value to what you suggested, but to no avail. I was actually references the following links: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/MBf8qvBpuVE and http://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs

Comment: Yes, still getting the same error. I'm actually fairly new to the mean stack/mean.io and didn't realize that if you create a package properly using the cli (mean package <nameofpkg>) it provides examples on how to set up the server routes. Let me try this and see if I can get the image to the server and I'll report back (just to rule out issues on the bk-end).